# Getting unreasonably good results when using a simple neural network for Price prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, prediction

I am trying to predict GPU prices. For this I have prepared a custom dataset of shape (135,39). I am using a simple multi layer neural network.

I gave my network a feature vector of size 39,1 which includes crypto prices and GPU prices of today. my y vector consists only of GPU prices one month from now.

When I train the network on the shuffled data, the predictions I get turn out to be really good. When I start predicting prices 12 months from now, I still get great results. This does not make any sense at all.

here are some of the results:

[image]
[image]

Here's what the dataset looks like
[image: Raw Dataset]

Input matrix X
[image: Input X]

Output y
[image]

And now here's the code

```
y_data = df.iloc[:,23:39]
y_data_mean = y_data.mean()
y_data_std = y_data.std()

norm_df=(df-df.mean())/df.std()
future_months = 1
X = norm_df[:len(df)-(5*future_months)]
y = norm_df.iloc[(5*future_months):,23:39]

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,shuffle=True)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(39,)))

model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=[tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size = 32, epochs = 2000)
```

Here's the train/test MSE loss.As per this graph I am not overfitting on the data. I should have used validation data but due to lack of dataset i only kept train and test datasets.

[image: MSE loss]

Comment: If you are sure you are not experiencing overfitting, it is likely you are encountering target leakage. It means that one of your input features (or more) may have a strong relation with your target.

Comment: @Kaveh any suggestions on how I can confirm if I am experiencing data leakage and how I can fix it ?

Comment: You can always make scatter plots of each input vs your output. You will see if there is a very strong relationship if there is a clear functional form in any of these plots, particularly if the spread around an underlying function is tight

Comment: Have you tried not shuffling the data so that the test set is a completely separate segment of time w.r.t. the training set?

Comment: @DanieleGrattarola I tried doing that, got weird results. for some GPUs the prices were predicted correctly but for some GPUs as time progressed, the predictions went more off. I thought that maybe because my regressor had not seen the test data trend, it was unable to predict that, but once I shuffled, I started getting this issue

Comment: @WVJoe Is this the same thing as having strong correlation? Dont we want data that has some correlation with the output?

Comment: I was just going off of the initial comment, explaining how to determine which input features could be very well correlated to the output. Now this would only be a problem if these input features wouldn't be available in a prediction environment, but I don't think you would have to worry about that in your case.

Comment: However, I would plot your predictions in a time series for this reason: your network can be modeling persistence. It would be essentially predicting the same price from the prediction time to the ouput time (of course it wouldn't be exact). But for most samples, I would guess this would result in low error but the model is not actually skillful. Also look at predictions for samples with serious price jumps and see if the model shows this as well (on your test set).